# In Westminster systems that are not Australian is the term “Dorothy Dixer” known?

Tags: terminology, westminster-system

In Australia, during questions without notice (the equivalent of PMQ), the softball questions from the government backbenchers to the PM (or other ministers) are called a Dorothy Dixer. Is this term known outside of Australia or are there equivalent terms?

Comment: [New Zealand doesn’t count, right?](https://thespinoff.co.nz/featured/13-10-2015/politics-how-to-fix-question-time-in-parliament-mps-media-and-other-experts-weigh-in/)

Comment: New Zealand does count .

Comment: It's entirely alien to Canadian political discourse as far as I can tell.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorothy_Dixer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be only used in Australian English.

It is not known in British English, and comments here suggest it is "alien to Canadian political discourse".

In Britain, soft questions and sycophantic questions are [common](https://blogs.spectator.co.uk/2020/01/hall-of-shame-this-weeks-pointless-questions-at-pmqs/) (but tend to get jeered) The government is not supposed to actually plant questions, and Speaker Bercow did warn the government back in 2015.

It is quite common for slang to cross between Australia and New Zealand, but New Zealand discussion [groups](https://www.kiwiblog.co.nz/2018/03/smart_move_from_the_greens.html) suggest that they are called "patsy questions" in New Zealand, and the expression "Dorothy Dixer" is not generally used.

Comment: From my experience, it's common in Canadian parliament that a "question" in Question Period isn't just a softball - it's 90% soapboxing and sycophancy with a vague prompt tacked on at the end to continue the thought. That is, mainly declarative and not even interpretable as a question. I can scarcely even find pundits criticizing this practice, let alone jeering within the House. Canadian political engagement at that level is really, really low.